# How to create in instance of an enumerated type using the node-java module

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to create an instance of an enumerated type using the node-java plugin for node.js.

I took a look through their examples but, I didn't see any examples with enumerated types.  I have a constructor that has an input that is an enumerated type.  I'm looking for something like:

```
var java = require("./node-java/index.js");
java.classpath.push("./DatabaseConnection.jar");

var DBType = java.newInstanceSync("database.ConnectionDB$SupportedDBTypes", "SQLServer");       
var conn = java.newInstanceSync("database.ConnectionDB", "192.168.2.100", 1360, "SQLEXPRESS", "LogDB_Admin", "sa", "pw", DBType );
```

Where the DatabaseConnection.jar has a class called ConnectionDB that contains an enumerated type called SupportedDBTypes and one of the types is SQLSERVER.

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this?